# Google Analytics just for event tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking

What i'm trying to build out is a html page that will be included on a partner site. The idea is we give the partner a JS file that then renders the html. We don't want to use an iFrame, so the new HTML would just be a  with links and copy.

We want to track link usage, and i though if i added a GA tracking snippet i could use it just for event tracking. I want to avoid getting page view data from the partner site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line `ga('send', 'pageview')` from the [JavaScript tracking snippet](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/tracking-snippet-reference), then you won't track any pageviews.

The normal tracking snippet looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

To not track pageviews, just remove the last line like so:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Comment: Hey Philip,

I had though of this, but i'm worried about ga() conflicts. could the ga be changed to something else?

Comment: I must admit I didn't thoroughly read your question before answer, but after re-reading it seems to me you're not asking about event tracking, you're asking about how to avoid conflicts when using analytics.js on a third-party site. If I were you I'd just start a new question and make that part more clear.

Comment: I am asking about event tracking, but there is the possibility that the partner page could have their own GA code running.

Comment: Right, and I've answered the event tracking part of the question. Answering the second part in these comments is less discoverable by other people.

Comment: Thanks Philip. I'm putting my reco to the client today. This method will be on the DO NOT do list. I'm actually thinking their backend team use the bit.ly api when generating the URL's.

Cheer!

Answer (score 2):

While Philip is technically correct you really should not include a complete copy of the analytics code in a third party website (this assumes that you are planning to inject this into an existing website as you say you "don't want to use an iframe", not sure if I understood you correctly) - for starters you'd need to use a named tracker so you do not overwrite their own tracker implementation (should there be one).

I would suggest the much more robust way via the [measurement protocol](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en) - use the [hit builder](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/) to assemble an event tracking call of your choice, use your clients partner id (I assume there is such a thing in the JS file you give to them) and send the tracking url in a simple onclick event when somebody clicks the link. That way there is no way you could interfere with an existing GA implementation.

The only other thing you would need to consider is privacy - when a user opts out from GA tracking the terms of service prohibit that you circumvent the opt-out, and your own onclick handler will not be affected by the opt-out. You should be okay if you use the partner id instead of the Google-generated client id (since your partner id says nothing about the visitor), but you should probably talk to a data protection officer first (or if you are an Adwords customer the Adwords support might be able to help you).

Comment: Thanks Eike, I hadn't thought about OnClick="" since i avoid inline JS at all costs. 

I'm not sure if this will be possible in my case as i don't have control on how the webApp is producing the links.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have control over the Urls used in the links ? You could set up a redirection service where the redirect page tracks the link and then sends the user to the intended destination. This would dispense with all inline tracking completely, but you would have to set up a rather reliable infrastructure to make sure the redirects will always work.

Comment: I don't, but this was presented as an option. I've been asked to explore a client side solution to this.

Ideally this is the fool proof way.